# Stage 15 of le tour ending at Mont Ventoux - how to get there?

Tags: france, sports-events, provence

I am playing with the thought of getting down to France to see some of the 100th edition of [le tour](http://www.letour.fr). The 15th stage ends spectacularly at Mont Ventoux after a 20.7 km climb at 7.5%.

[image: climbing mont ventoux]
pic by [jack_of_hearts_398](http://www.flickr.com/photos/22991060@N04/)

What do I need to think of to do this? Are there buses that transports visitors or is it better to rent a car. How much in advance to I need to be there?

The tour then continues to the area around Gap. Is it viable to stay in or near Gap and visit Mont Ventoux over day for the stage finish?

Comment: Gap sounds a bit far. You'd better find closer accommodation, in Vaison-la-Romaine and its area, or I would say the furthest in Orange. For finding housing, you can find help in the related question: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/10390/i-am-looking-for-a-hotel-search-engine-for-rural-areas

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The usual way is to go there (Mont Ventoux or any other stage with mountains) with an RV the day before.

[image]

(image kindly stolen [from a french blog](http://chtoric67.canalblog.com/archives/2009/07/24/14839451.html))

Comment: I doubt if everybody is doing it like that. If I see the amount of people along the route on tv, I don't think they all fit in these RVs. I.e. 20 people / RV length. I thought most people are just walking or cycling up the mountain.

Comment: @Bernhard - Most of the route of Tour de France runs through or near small or big cities. This is where you can see crowd. Some parts of hilly stages, like the Mont Ventoux, are not so populated and people have to come from far places long before to find an interesting spot. Not everybody has an RV; tents also are common (you can see some in the picture's background).

Comment: @mouviciel - but you need your own transport then?

Comment: @froderik - Yes, you need a vehicle, be it a bicycle, motorbike, car. But I'm afraid that no public transport or special bus tour exist.

Comment: I see - bring a tent and rent a car then! Is it possible to get there in the early morning? When will the roads close prior to the race?